# How do I make tradingview buy and sell signals?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

My problem is in tradingview pinescript codes. I give buy and sell signals. The problem is that it gives the same signal repeatedly. I want it to repeat the signal once without giving another signal.

The signal is repeated every time the situation occurs.

```
    //@version=5 indicator("varant", "", true) int legsInput = input.int(30, "Pivot Legs")



color pHiColorInput = input.color(color.green, "High pivots")          color pLoColorInput = input.color(color.green, "Low pivots")

color artiColorInput = input.color(color.blue, "arti değer") color ucColorInput = input.color(color.red, "uc değer")                   color ortaColorInput = input.color(color.black, "Orta değer")          color ikiColorInput = input.color(color.red, "iki değer")            color eksiColorInput = input.color(color.blue, "eksi değer")


//  Pivot seviye değişkenlerini başlat. var float pHi = na var float pLo = na

var float arti = na var float uc = na var float orta = na var float iki = na var float eksi = na


//  Yeni bir pivot algılandığında değeri kaydediyor. pHi := nz(ta.pivothigh(legsInput, legsInput), pHi) pLo := nz(ta.pivotlow( legsInput, legsInput), pLo)

arti := nz(((pHi-pLo)/1.618)+pHi) uc := nz(pHi-((pHi-pLo)/2.618)) orta := nz((pHi+pLo)/2) iki := nz(pHi-((pHi-pLo)/1.618)) eksi := nz(pLo-((pHi-pLo)/1.618))


//  Yeni bir pivot algılandığında değeri kaydediyor. pHi := nz(ta.pivothigh(legsInput, legsInput), pHi) pLo := nz(ta.pivotlow( legsInput, legsInput), pLo)

arti := nz(((pHi-pLo)/1.618)+pHi) uc := nz(pHi-((pHi-pLo)/2.618)) orta := nz((pHi+pLo)/2) iki := nz(pHi-((pHi-pLo)/1.618)) eksi := nz(pLo-((pHi-pLo)/1.618)) sahtepHi = pHi sahtepLo = pLo


//  Yeni bir pivot algılandığında renk çizmiyor. //plot(pHi, "High", ta.change(pLo) ? na : pHiColorInput, 2, plot.style_line) //plot(pLo, "Low",  ta.change(pHi) ? na : pLoColorInput, 2, plot.style_line)

//plot(arti, "arti", ta.change(arti) ?  artiColorInput : artiColorInput, 1, plot.style_line) //plot(uc , "uc", ta.change(uc) ?  ucColorInput : ucColorInput, 1, plot.style_line) //plot(orta, "Mid", ta.change(orta) ?  ortaColorInput : ortaColorInput, 1, plot.style_line) //plot(iki , "iki", ta.change(iki) ?  ikiColorInput : ikiColorInput, 1, plot.style_line) //plot(eksi, "eksi", ta.change(eksi) ?  eksiColorInput : eksiColorInput, 1, plot.style_line)


pricenow= ta.ema(close,1) //plot(ta.ema(close,1),color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100))

/// bool isCond1 = (ta.crossover(pricenow, eksi)) plotshape(series = isCond1 , style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=#ff0000, size=size.tiny, text="wait to buy") /// bool isCond2 = (ta.crossunder(pricenow, eksi)) plotshape(series = isCond2 , style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=#0000ff, size=size.tiny, text="close sell") /// bool isCond3 = (ta.crossover(pricenow, arti)) plotshape(series = isCond3 , style=shape.cross, location=location.belowbar, color=#0000FF, size=size.tiny, text="wait to sell") /// bool isCond4 = (ta.crossunder(pricenow, sahtepHi*0.99)) plotshape(series = isCond4 , style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=#00ff00, size=size.tiny, text="sell") /// bool isCond5 = (ta.crossover(pricenow, sahtepLo*1.01)) plotshape(series = isCond5 , style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=#00ff00, size=size.tiny, text="buy") /// bool isCond6 = (ta.crossover(pricenow, sahtepHi*1.01)) plotshape(series = isCond6 , style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color=#00ff00, size=size.tiny, text="close sell")
```

Comment: Please fix your code.